# Play videos retrieved from youtube api v3

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

Using Youtube API V3, I can extract the thumbnails of videos from a user's activity feed (using the [activities](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities#resource) list from the api).

What I am trying to achieve is, when the user clicks on the video, the video should be played. I have looked at iframes. however the activities list on the api, does not show how to get the url for the video, but a different the [Videos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource) resource shows a player.embedHtml field, however I am confused, how to integrate it to my code.

```
    var activityId, nextPageToken, prevPageToken, videoSnippet;

// Once the api loads call a function to get the uploads playlist id.
function handleAPILoaded() {
  requestUserUploadsactivityId();
}

//Retrieve the uploads playlist id.
function requestUserUploadsactivityId() {
  // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list
  var request = gapi.client.youtube.activities.list({
    // mine: '' indicates that we want to retrieve the channel for the authenticated user.
    home: 'true',
    part: 'snippet'
  });
  request.execute(function(response) {
    //structure of content.details
    //https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#resource
    console.log(response);
    activityId = response.items[0].id;
    requestVideoPlaylist(activityId);
  });
}

// Retrieve a playist of videos.
function requestVideoPlaylist(home, pageToken) {
  $('#video-container').html('');
  var requestOptions = {
    home: 'true',
    part: 'snippet',
    maxResults: 12
  };
  if (pageToken) {
    requestOptions.pageToken = pageToken;
  }
  var request = gapi.client.youtube.activities.list(requestOptions);
  request.execute(function(response) {


    var activityItems = response.result.items;
    if (activityItems) {
      // For each result lets show a thumbnail.
      jQuery.each(activityItems, function(index, item) {
        createDisplayThumbnail(item.snippet);

      });
    } else {
      $('#video-container').html('Sorry you have no activities on your feed');
    }
  });
}


// Create a thumbnail for a video snippet.
function createDisplayThumbnail(videoSnippet) {
  var titleEl = $('<h4>');
  titleEl.addClass('video-title');
  $(titleEl).html(videoSnippet.title);
  var thumbnailUrl = videoSnippet.thumbnails.default.url;
   console.log(videoSnippet);
  var div = $('<div>');
  div.addClass('video-content');
  div.css('backgroundImage', 'url("' + thumbnailUrl + '")');
  div.append(titleEl);
  $('#video-container').append(div);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The activities list includes several activity types :

upload, like, favorite, comment, subscription, playlistItem, recommendation, bulletin, social ..

and only some kind of activities are related to a video. Then you can only retrieve the videoId from the contentDetails when the type of activity is related to a video. You can use the videoId to show the video.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities

You have a good example in "YouTube Topic Explorer". In this App you can retrieve the social activities and retrieve the videoId from this kind of activities

https://code.google.com/p/yt-topic-explorer/source/browse/app/scripts/controllers/logged-in.js

```
$scope.social = function() {
    $rootScope.topicResults = [];
    $rootScope.spinner.spin($('#spinner')[0]);

        youtube({
          method: 'GET',
          service: 'activities',
          params: {
                part: 'id,snippet,contentDetails',
                home: true,
                maxResults: constants.YOUTUBE_API_MAX_RESULTS
          },
          callback: function(response) {
                  if ('items' in response) {
                          $scope.videoIds = [];
                          $scope.personalizedTopics = [];
                          angular.forEach(response.items, function(activity) {
                                if ((activity.snippet.type == constants.SOCIAL_TYPE)&&(activity.contentDetails.social.resourceId.videoId)){
                                        $scope.videoIds.push(activity.contentDetails.social.resourceId.videoId);
                                }
                          });
                  }
                  getTopicsForVideoIds();
          }
        });
  }
```

and you have an example of how to show the video:

https://code.google.com/p/yt-topic-explorer/source/browse/app/scripts/controllers/main.js

```
 function playVideo(container, videoId) {
    var width = container.offsetWidth;
    var height = container.offsetHeight;

    new YT.Player(container, {
      videoId: videoId,
      width: width,
      height: height,
      playerVars: {
        autoplay: 1,
        controls: 2,
        modestbranding: 1,
        rel: 0,
        showInfo: 0
      }
    });
```

Comment: ! thanks so much,is there a demo for this anywhere? also what does the getTopicsForvideoIds() method do? it looks a bit complicated.

Comment: Check this project https://code.google.com/p/yt-topic-explorer/ Yes, it is a bit complicated because it shows how to integrate freebase API with YouTube Data API